# How to make generic type deque?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, deque, type-safety

I am creating a deque using generic type E...
Having trouble initializing some sort of generic array, while being type safe, have tried casting, however this is `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object[] to E[]`

```
public class DequeCyclic<E> implements Deque<E> {
   private E[] line;

   public DequeCyclic(int size) {
   E[] line = (E[])new Object[size];
   }
}
```

Could I put in `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to ignore the type safety issue?
What is another way to create the generic deque/array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Comment: Generally, this is done by doing a cast on the getters/dequeue method, and keeping it as an Object[].